# Programmable shortcut keys

Tags: rstudio

Is there any way to assign custom R code to RStudio IDE shortcut keys? For example I would like to execute specific R code into my session whenever I press `CRTL + SHIFT + S`.

I know that there is a "Source on Save" option, but the question here is more general.

Answer (score 0):

More recently, there is this [shrtcts](https://github.com/gadenbuie/shrtcts) package which works well within RStudio and allows for fully customized shortcuts on project basis.

---

Old solution was to set the RStudio IDE Project option to "package", which enables the `CTRL + SHIFT + L` shortkey to execute `devtools::load_all(".")`.

Then in `.Rprofile` I change the functionality of `devtools::load_all(".")`:

```
rlang::env_binding_unlock(env = asNamespace('devtools'))
assign('load_all', function(x) source('some_script.r'), envir = asNamespace('devtools'))
rlang::env_binding_lock(env = asNamespace('devtools'))
```

Now when I press `CTRL + SHIFT + L` (by default), `some_script.r` gets sourced.